# Protractor waitForAngularEnabled

Tags: angular, protractor

waitForAngularEnabled doesn't seem to work.

Use case :
- waitForAngularEnabled to false to get sso page and fill user/password fields
-  return to angular app and waitForAngularEnabled to true causes error

i've create a simple angular app projet to reproduce it, simple run ng e2e

https://github.com/lilletech/protractor-issue

Answer (score 1):

You should break your tests up more, both for your sake with debugging and to mitigate issues with the protractor control flow.  Changing your tests to the following works:

```
import { browser, element, by } from 'protractor';

describe('protractor-test-project App', () => {

    it('goes to google', () => {
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
        browser.get('https://www.google.com');
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('https://www.google.com/');
    });

    it('enters a search', () => {
        const inputEl = element(by.id('lst-ib'));
        browser.wait(() => inputEl.isPresent(), 10000, 'too long');
        inputEl.sendKeys("protractor issue waitForAngularEnabled");
        expect(inputEl.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('protractor issue waitForAngularEnabled');
    });

    it('returns to angular page', () => {
        browser.get('/');
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
        const titleElement = element(by.id("title"));
        expect(titleElement.isPresent());
    });
});
```

Can't say for sure why the control flow wouldn't be handling this properly, but this seems to be caused by having two `waitForAngularEnabled` in the same spec (also might be because of navigating twice).  If you disable your second one (where you re-enable it), your test works.

So you can either use my solution above which breaks them out into multiple steps, or you can nest the call under `browser.get` which also seems to work i.e.

```
   browser.get('/').then(() => {
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
    });
```

Again, not sure why exactly that would happen.  The control flow *should* be synchronizing these steps so using `.then()` shouldnt be necessary... but apparently it is.  Breaking tests out into multiple `it` blocks also helps protractor synchronize things in the proper order

Answer (score 0):

Using `waitForAngularEnabled` multiple times in the same test can be done, but requires a non-obvious addition of `browser.get`. Intuitively, most people think that setting `waitForAngularEnabled(true)` waits for protractor to pick up Angular tasks again but this returns a promise. Most people use it in a way where they can disable it on non-Angular pages and re-enable it on Angular pages, aka in a synchronous way.  To solve this, you can use the following:

```
// do things on your Angular application

waitForAngularEnabled(false)

// do things on non-angular page

waitForAngularEnabled(true)
browser.get('/home') // this is a page from your Angular application
```

The `browser.get` function blocks until the Angular page is loaded.