# Protractor login issue

Tags: angular, protractor

I'm facing with a login issue that i can not solve.
The scenario is:
1. browser gets the main page (this is an agular enaled site)
2. clicking on login link
3. this loads a non angular site
4. entering credentials and clicking login
5. this redirects back to the angular site (adds header infos)
6. the site loads and detects the succesfull authentication

I'm unable to get back on track from point 5. Protractor keeps getting time out.

I tried manipulating the waitforangularenabled as it is required for the non-angular login. But unable to switch it back.

What is the correct point to do so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51261318/protractor-waitforangularenabled/51269748#51269748 by @gunderson should help

Comment: protractor will detect the opening page is angular or not only when calling `browser.get(<url>)`. Therefor page opened by `click` or `redirect by browser` should not trigger the examining of angular.  So you only need to set `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` before any `browser.get(<non angular page>)`.

Answer (score 0):

you should use:

```
    **For non-angular navigation**

    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

   **for angular navigation**

   browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
```

Comment: ignoreSynchronization is deprecated and going away someday. Better to use waitForAngularEnabled as the person did. But the question asks at exactly what point to set the value.

Comment: Yes i use waitForAngularEnabled, and i set it to false after the login link cliked on the angular site and try to switch it on after clicking on the login on the non angular site. I guess the redirection is the issue for protractor but unable to find the sweet spot.